# binary search for strings in java

Tags: java, string, binary-search

I have an array of strings which is sorted by default. I want a binary search over this list in java. Is there any buit-in binary search function for strings in java?

Comment: Collections.binarySearch() takes a List :)

Comment: Did you see `Related questions & answers` that showed up while you typed this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) utility classes have binary-search methods.

Answer (score 0):

what if they dont have?

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
.
.
.
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
.
.
.
}
```